# Uptime for individual service

Tags: linux, ubuntu, service, daemon, uptime

I am running multiple unicorn processes on my production server. Now I want to check the individual service uptime of my services. For instance if any unicorn process restart automatically, it should start recording its uptime. By this means I want to calculate what is the uptime of the service since its last `start/restart/reload`
Note: Here I am not talking about the server uptime which can be known by using `uptime` command like below.

```
$ uptime
 19:11:25 up 2 days, 21:28,  1 user,  load average: 0.11, 0.09, 0.11
```

I would like to know the uptime of individual service like uptime of nginx

Is it possible to know it somehow?

Comment: is there a reason this solution will not work?  just grep the results for the name of the service you are looking for or the related daemon.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731234/how-to-get-the-start-time-of-a-long-running-linux-process

Comment: Check the creation times of the process-id named entries in `/proc/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) works great for this.

The `monit status` command shows this information clearly:

```
Process 'ssh'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               11239
  parent pid                        1
  uid                               0
  effective uid                     0
  gid                               0
  uptime                            32d 5h 1m
  children                          230
  memory                            1.2 MB
  memory total                      2.0 GB
  memory percent                    0.0%
  memory percent total              0.6%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
  cpu percent total                 0.1%
  data collected                    Mon, 09 Jan 2017 11:34:08

Process 'cron'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               669744
  parent pid                        1
  uid                               0
  effective uid                     0
  gid                               0
  uptime                            1m
  children                          0
  memory                            1.2 MB
  memory total                      1.2 MB
  memory percent                    0.0%
  memory percent total              0.0%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
  cpu percent total                 0.0%
  data collected                    Mon, 09 Jan 2017 11:34:08

Process 'newrelic'
  status                            Running
  monitoring status                 Monitored
  pid                               11377
  parent pid                        1
  uid                               495
  effective uid                     495
  gid                               495
  uptime                            32d 5h 1m
  children                          1
  memory                            500.0 kB
  memory total                      8.3 MB
  memory percent                    0.0%
  memory percent total              0.0%
  cpu percent                       0.0%
  cpu percent total                 0.0%
  data collected                    Mon, 09 Jan 2017 11:34:08
```